# Importing YAML data at build-time in Webpack, and making it available as parsed data at runtime

Tags: vue.js, webpack, yaml, loader

I'm attempting to import the contents of a YAML file at build-time, and make the parsed content available to my application somehow.

This is in a Webpack project that I've been tasked with building a new feature for. The project is using Vue. I have pretty much 0 experience with Webpack. I've installed the `js-yaml-loader` package, and have configured Webpack with it as such:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    ...,
    {
      test: /\.ya?ml$/,
      include: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/data'),
      loader: 'js-yaml-loader'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

As far as I understand it, this will - at build time - traverse the `src/data` folder for YAML files, and load them, using the `js-yaml-loader` loader, which will then somehow include the parsed content of those files somewhere. But when I search the generated output, the keys/values contained in the YAML are nowhere to be found.

Am I going about this correctly? Or is there something I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it with Vue + TypeScript:

1. Create a yaml file e.g. `test.yaml`.
2. Create typings for it with e.g. `test.yaml.d.ts`, register it to be used with `js-yaml-loader` e.g.:

   ```js
      declare module 'js-yaml-loader!*' { 
             export interface TestYaml {
                    testProperty: string;
             }

             const content: TestYaml ;
             export default content;
      }
   ```
3. Import it using `import { MyYamlFile} from 'js-yaml-loader!./../test.yaml';`

Example:

- [`application.yaml` the YAML file](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/d235dee95514a01745aef9479d07f88ffb4b40b8/src/application/application.yaml)
- [`application.d.ts` the typings file](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/d235dee95514a01745aef9479d07f88ffb4b40b8/src/application/application.yaml)
- [`ApplicationParser.ts` file importing the yaml file](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/d235dee95514a01745aef9479d07f88ffb4b40b8/src/application/Parser/ApplicationParser.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your .yaml file in some source file in your project.

You can imagine webpack loaders defined in `module.rules` as some scripts or programs that will run when you are trying to import a file fulfilling some pattern (`test` property) (there can be also another [condition](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) that should be fulfilled, e.g. your `include` condition). The loader will take your file as an input and provide some output.

So you need to import your file, e.g. in some of your .js file:

```js
import myYamlFile from './file.yml';
```

Then according to [js-yaml-loader documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) you have your file as a javascript object in variable `myYamlFile`, see the documentation of js-yaml parser:

https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml

Comment: Curious. Not sure what I had done wrong before, but I couldn't get it to work like that. I think it might have been malformed YAML that was throwing a red-herring error. The solution I posted works, however. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I didn't even have to modify the Webpack config. I just did this:

```
import TextData from 'js-yaml-loader!../data/texts.yaml';
import Texts from './vue/plugins/texts';
Vue.use(Texts, {
    texts: TextData,
});
```

Which imports the text data as a JS oject and injects in into the options for my `Texts` Vue plugin.

Comment: Yes, you just use the loader inline: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge (loading yaml files in vuejs at build time), and I used [vue-cli-plugin-yaml](https://github.com/edus44/vue-cli-plugin-yaml).

No webpack configuration needed, and once installed you can import the files easily.

```
import myData from './myData.yaml';
console.log(myData);
```